# Matlab: Finding interpolated x value given y value when data is in an array

Tags: matlab

I have an array of x values and an array of y values. When plotted, there are two peaks where the slope in those regions is very steep. My goal is to find the FWHM of those peaks. I can find the value of y at half maximum, but given the steepness of the slope and the fact that my data is in an array, I am having difficulty finding the 4 x-values which correspond to this y-value.

I was thinking of using a loop to find the points directly before and after the given y-value, then using those to fit a line (the high slope makes it so the curve can be approximated by a linear equation in that small region) and using those equations to find the interpolated x-values, from which I can calculate the full width.

Here is my coding for this so far:

```
    % yarray is list of y values
    % A = y value where I need to find the 4 corresponding x values 
    for k = 1:length(yarray)-1
        if yarray(k+1) <= A & yarray(k) >= A
            M = [yarray(k) yarray(k+1) k k+1]
        elseif yarray(k+1) >= A & yarray(k) <= A
            M = [yarray(k) yarray(k+1) k k+1]
        end
    end
```

When I run this code, there are 4 M arrays, but each time it gets overwritten. How can I "save" those arrays so I can recall later? Is there a simpler approach to this problem? Let me know if I can clarify my question. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Formatted your code. Please check that it follows now your intention. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can provide an answer to saving the arrays for later use and I can think of three approaches to this.

1) Save the arrays to a matfile.  Place the following line after your conditional statements to save the array to a matfile named `saved_array_k.mat` where `k` is the iteration number.

```
M = [yarray(k) yarray(k+1) k k+1];
save(['saved_array_' num2str(k) '.mat'],'M');
```

2) You can also use an `eval` call to dynamically create the four arrays.  Replace each assignment statement in your conditional expression with something like:

```
eval(['M' num2str(k) '= [yarray(k) yarray(k+1) k k+1];']);
```

In your case, this will generate the variables,`M1`, `M2`, `M3`, `M4` and each will contain the information you want.

3) Create a matrix with the results where each row of the matrix contains the data you want.  (this is probably best). Create a matrix `M` like

```
M = zeros(4); % each of your arrays has length 4 and there are 4 of them
```

In your assignment statements use:

```
M(:,k) = [yarray(k) yarray(k+1) k k+1];
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is simpler approach to your problem and yes, you should clarify your question. (For example, don't assume that acronyms like `FWHM` are commonly known and you may like to describe where your data is coming from and is your question really related to interpolation).

Anyway, a simple demonstration with one peak may clarify the situation:

```
>>> x= linspace(0, pi, 100); y= sin(x);
>>> mi= min(y); ma= max(y);
>>> x_above= x(y> (ma- mi)/ 2);
>>> fwhm= x_above(end)- x_above(1)
fwhm =  2.0627
```